# How should I connect and move my local mongoose db to mongodb cloud atlas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, configure

When I start my server, an error was shown like this:

```
Error in DB connection : Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT yky-api-ajgvf.mongodb.net
```

I tried many times to work properly in order to fix this problem. I couldn't even deploy my project on heroku properly yet. I love nodejs so much but now I just want to give up continuously learning Nodejs for now.

Someone help me to solve my problem if possible. I'm the one who is learning Node.Js. It's been around 4 or 5 months. Before I decided to leran PHP, but now I'm still trying to learn nodejs.

I'm a newbie. :)

This is my config database code in my small project.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const log = console.log

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://chanlay:chanlay123@yky-api-ajgvf.mongodb.net/yky-blog-api?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
    useNewUrlParser: true
}, (err) => { 
    if (!err) {
        log('MongoDB Connection Succeeded.')
    } else {
        log('Error in DB connection : ' + err)
    }
});

require('../models/posts')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mongoose.connect()` can look like this ([docs reference](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#callback)):

```
mongoose.connect(uri, options, function(error) {
  // Check error in initial connection. There is no 2nd param to the callback.
});

// Or using promises
mongoose.connect(uri, options).then(
  () => { /** ready to use. The `mongoose.connect()` promise resolves to mongoose instance. */ },
  err => { /** handle initial connection error */ }
);
```

Before demonstrating further, first of all, this block of yours is **wrong**:

```
if (!err) {
        log('MongoDB Connection Succeeded.')
    }
```

error handling doesn't work that way, this condition will never happen, as when there's no error, there is no reason to call error callback function which checks this condition.

Instead use **.then()** block, as a successful connection returns a Promise:

```
mongoose.connect(uri, options).then(
  () => { console.log('MongoDB Connection Succeeded.') },
  err => { console.log(err) }
); 

// OR use .catch() after .then()

mongoose.connect(uri, options).then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connection Succeeded.')).catch( err => console.log(err))
```

---

**Your answer:** set `socketTimeoutMS` to 60000 or 90000.
If still didn't work,  add `connectTimeoutMS=90000` and `reconnectTries=1000` to `options` too.

---

Declare a new variable named `options` (the name is arbitrary, but better follow the convention), and you put your `useNewUrlParser: true` also there ([reference](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#options)):

```
const options = {
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   socketTimeoutMS: 60000 //or 90000
 }
```

**Tip:** You can also specify driver options in your connection string as parameters in the query string portion of the URI ([reference](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connection-string-options)):

`{main-url}?socketTimeoutMS=90000`, that is:

```
const uri = mongodb+srv://chanlay:chanlay123@yky-api-ajgvf.mongodb.net/yky-blog-api?retryWrites=true&w=majority?socketTimeoutMS=90000
```

but stick with `options` variable as it's cleaner, more readable, and easier to maintain (otherwise you would put everything in  a string which makes it harder for you to read and debug).

Please let me know by leaving to my answer a comment either as a feedback or reporting the persistent error.

Comment: Yes my brother. I will try with your way. After I had solved this problem, I'll reply you right away.

Comment: @ChanMyaeMaung add `connectTimeoutMS=90000` and `reconnectTries=1000` to `options`. Which version of `mongoose` do you use?

Comment: It's has been worked my brother. But, I connect and linked with Mongolab in order to deploy with Heroku. My mongoose version is 5.6.1